# How to change a pointer address in a singly linked list using the "->" operator

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write my own code for the erase function used in dynamic structures (lists specifically) of the stl library for a school project

What I had in mind was to do a loop until i found the node prior to the one i wanted to delete.

```
while (loop->next!= NULL){
        if (loop->next==pValue){
        break;
    }
    else {
            loop->next;
    }
}   
prev=loop;
delete loop;
```

Then I want to update its pointer and instead of having it point to the node to be deleted, i want it to point to the node after the one i'm going to delete.
So can i do this?

```
*(prev->next)=*(pValue->next);
```

in case i can't, what should i do?

Here's my function erase

```
template <class T>
void list<T>::erase(pos pValue){
    list<T>::pos prev;
    list<T>::pos temp=pValue->next;
    list<T>::pos loop=list<T>::first();
    while (loop->next!= NULL){
        if (loop->next==pValue){
            break;
        }
        else {
            loop->next;
        }
    }   
    prev=loop;
    delete loop;

    *(prev->next)=*(pValue->next);

    delete list<T>::get(pValue);
}
```

And here's part of my class list

```
 template <class T>
 class list {
    node<T> *pFirst;
    int n;
    public:
        typedef node<T> *pos;
        void erase(pos pValue);
};
```

And the structure of the node:

```
 template <class T>
 class node {
     public:
        T info;
        node<T> *next;
 };
```

Comment: `loop->next;` doesn't do anything.  Perhaps you meant `loop = loop->next;`

Comment: You are thinking right. You need `prev->next` to point to `current->next` before `current` is deleted. It is often helpful to pull out an 8.5x11 sheet of paper and pencil and draw the nodes and the pointer connections to figure out which pointers need to be re-wired and in what order.

Comment: We will also accept 11x17 pages of paper. The important port is visualizing the list.

Comment: There are couple of things wrong with your code. [Look here to see a correct example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-3-deleting-node/)